# Conditional list comprehension without else

Tags: python

I have the following solution, however its wasteful to loop over the data again to remove pointless white-space (" ") placed in to satisfy the compiler. *I wish to keep this solution compact and in-line as shown.*

**How could I rewrite this to only return values on *one* condition?**

```
ans = [x[0] if x[1]==minimum else " " for x in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehensions support the inclusion of a predicate to filter the items.

I think you want:

```
ans = [x[0] for x in zip(a,b) if x[1]==minimum]
```

or maybe a little clearer like this:

```
ans = [x for (x,y) in zip(a,b) if y==minimum]
```

Comment: @AidenFaulconer I don't understand "use z as the 2nd index per zip item" and "to loop with is i+1"

Comment: Because you can use a pair of variables `(x,y)` to iterate through your `zip`, and each variable is assigned one part of the zipped-up item. It's called "unpacking".